# Compare and print lines from second file

Tags: awk

Would like to compare second field from F11.txt and first field from F22.txt then Print match cases only from both the files:

F11.txt

```
a,10,zzz
b,20,zzz
c,50,zzz
```

F22.txt

```
10,yyy
20,yyy
30,yyy
40,yyy
```

Have tried the below command

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0, a[$1]}'  f22.txt f11.txt
```

Got the output from F11.txt only missing the corresponding entries from F22.txt
a,10,zzz,
b,20,zzz,

where to change the code to print the line items from F22.txt as  well.

Expected output:

```
a,10,zzz,10,yyy
b,20,zzz,20,yyy
```

Comment: Check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/search/label/awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your `awk`,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next} $2 in a{print $0, a[$2]}' f22.txt f11.txt
```

Everything is correct. But you have to use `a[$2]` instead of `a[$1]` while printing.

Another `awk` version,

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in a){print $0,a[$2]}' OFS=, f22.txt f11.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sat, how to print only selective columns from f22.txt instead of printing entire line from f22.txt , like wants to print only 1st field of f22.txt

Comment: like the OP would be a,10,zzz,10
b,20,zzz,20

Comment: @AVN, Using `split`. Ex: `split(a[$2],arr,",");print $0,arr[1]` **(OR)** Instead of storing the whole line (`$0`) into `a`, you can store specific field only (`$1`). Ex: `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next}`

Answer (score 0):

`join` is the bash tool that is designed for these kind of tasks

```
$ join -t, -1 2 -2 1 file1 file2
10,a,zzz,yyy
20,b,zzz,yyy
```

- `-t` is the field separator
- `-1` defines the column to check for on `file1`
- `-2` defines the column to check for on `file2`

You see that the matched column is only printed once, and that is normally desired behavior, because otherwise you have two identical columns, which would be redundant. Of course you know how the reshuffle the columns using, for example, `awk`